# 1/4 inch plastic water line to 1/2 inch refrigerator connection

Tags: plumbing, water, pipe, refrigerator, plumbing-fixture

I am on the last step of installing a reverse osmosis water filtration system underneath the kitchen sink. After the water is filtered, I have two options;

1. connect the final blue 1/4 inch outer diameter plastic water line to the faucet included with the system

or

2. somehow connect the final 1/4 inch outer diameter plastic water line to the water intake on my refrigerator.

I want to connect the 1/4 inch outer diameter plastic water line from water filter directly to my refrigerator however I am unsure what adapter I need since the water intake for the refrigerator is connected to a 1/2 inch outer diameter steel braided line. The steel braided line contains unfiltered water and I plan to either take out that line from the saddle valve and shut off the saddle valve.

So my question is, what adapter do I need to connect a 1/4 inch OD plastic tube to my refrigerator water intake. I am unsure of the inner diameter of the water intake hole on my refigerator but the current steel braided hose on there has an outer diameter of 1/2 inch which has a nut at the end of the hose which screws onto the refrigerator water intake.

Also, that blue plastic line coming up from where the steel braided hose feeds only the ice maker and not the water dispenser.

[image]

Comment: Duplicated and answered here : https://diy.stackexchange.com/q/162445/97780

Comment: I got an answer to every question for my ro system besides this one question